# Make walk cycle easier?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I don't know how to post a visual of this so I'll try to explain it as best as I can. I'm trying to animate a character walking from one location to another. I've been manually posing the character and setting keyframes, starting at one location and trying to get her to another. It's pretty complicated because she's gotta turn at one point. Is there a way I can animate a walk cycle, and then take that animation and just drag it across the floor so that I don't have to worry about placing the feet in the right spot and maintaining a certain rhythm? That would really make things easier.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8jMYuGu_IU) showing how to follow a path help?

Comment: Yes very much so, thank you!

Comment: Good! No problem.